# Require selecting the tag in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to require the user to select the tag.

To select from the options not for the field.

Because if the field is required, then after the tag selection, something should be written in the field.

[image]

```
if( !function_exists('qa_tag_template') ):
function qa_tag_template(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/template" id="tag_item">

        <input type="hidden" name="tags[]" value="{{= stripHTML(name) }}"       />
        {{= stripHTML(name) }} <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function stripHTML(html)
        {
           var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
           tmp.innerHTML = html;
           return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
endif;**strong text**
```